# Реализация универсальных методов

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WindowsForms
Что-то запутался в универсальных методах и пр..

**Основная цель** - обращение к методу объекта через интерфейс (Interface).

**Описание**: объект должен иметь метод VIEW с возможностью принимать в качестве параметра разные "классы".

**Что пробовал делать**: объявляю в интерфейсе IAppObject метод `void View<T>(T Model) where T : class`. Казалось бы так и должно быть, но мне надо в дальнейшем в наследнике этого интерфейса реализовать несколько методов VIEW в зависимости от того, какой класс передан в качестве `<T>`. Т.е. если я передаю туда например MyClassA - то метод View должен делать одно, если передаю MyClassB - то метод View должен делать другое. Обычно такое реализовывают через перегрузку методов, но интерфейс применяется к разным классам у которых должен быть метод View и не каждый из них должен принимать MyClassA, соответственно перегрузку методов в Интерфейсе делать нельзя - это создаст кучу ненужных реализаций в наследнике.
Пробовал делать в наследнике через `where T: MyClassA`, но требует конкретную реализацию условия как в интерфейсе.

Пример интерфейса:

```
public interface IAppObject : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Просмотр видимой части объекта "по умолчанию".
    /// </summary>
    void View();
    /// <summary>
    /// Просмотр видимой части объекта в зависимости от переданной модели.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="Model"></param>
    void View<T>(T Model) where T : class;
    /// <summary>
    /// Событие - уничтожение текущего объекта.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler EventRemoveObject;
}
```

Пример метода View реализованного в классе:

```
/// <summary>
/// Показать визуальную часть от модели.
/// </summary>
void IAppObject.View<T>(T Model)
{
    UserSessionModel us = Model as UserSessionModel;
    this.View(us);
}
/// <summary>
/// Показать визуальную часть от модели.
/// </summary>
public void View<T>(T Model) where T : UserSessionModel
{

}
```

Как видно из примера реализации метода View в наследнике интерфейса, для того, чтобы вызвать метод перегрузки, понадобится определять какой тип имеет переданный параметр T - т.е. сотворять кучу if,swith и прочей чепухи.. Просто передать в качестве параметра Model не получится, т.к. будет ругаться на отсутствие явного преобразования к UserSessionModel.

**Вопрос**: как можно описать в интерфейсе (Interface) метод (возможно универсальный), но реализацию в наследнике выполнить перегруженным методом ? PS: использовать наследование класса (простого/абстрактного) не хотелось бы, интересует именно через Interface.

Comment: @rdorn я выкрутился из ситуации через рефлексия, не совсем то, что хотелось бы, но возможно иначе​ никак. опишите предполагаемый метод решения свой. суть задачи такова что в интерфейсе есть метод принимающий в качестве параметра любой класс. в классе наследнике интерфейса реализация этого метода должна работать по принципу перегрузки методов принимающих конкретный класс, чтобы избежать конструкций if,swith и т.п.

Comment: @rdorn чтото на подобии mvc в asp.net когда контроллер вызывает конкретную view в зависимости от модели что вы ему передали, только не на основе вызова класса из сборки по наименованию, а вызова метода с конкретным параметром. я это сделал через рефлексию, но надеюсь что есть другие способы.

Comment: @rdorn, приведите пример краткий, что имеете ввиду под "обобщенный" и реализация "конкретики" в наследнике, не хочется плохих мыслей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение через рефлексию** (не то, что хотелось бы, но ...):

Интерфейс:

```
public interface IAppObject : IDisposable
{
    void View();
    void View<T>(T Model) where T : AModel;
    event EventHandler EventRemoveObject;
}
```

Пришлось использовать 1 общий класс для всех моделей, чтобы "централизовать" условие для ограничения в универсальном методе.

Реализация "перегрузки" (термин скорее неверный, но действие похожее) универсального метода в классе с использованием рефлексии:

```
void IAppObject.View()
{
    this.RemoveObject(null, null);
}
// Данный метод описан возможно неверно, т.к на момент составления
// ответа реализацию этого метода для удобства пришлось сделать через абстрактный класс
public IAppObject.View<T>(T Model)
{
    Type th = this.GetType();
    MethodInfo mi = th.GetMethod("View", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { Model.GetType() }, null);
    mi?.Invoke(this, new object[] { Model });
}
// Метод класса используемый для перегрузки.
public void View(UserSessionModel Model)
{

}
```

Пример обращения:

```
IAppObject StartObject = new AppObject();
StartObject.View(new UserSessionModel());
```

При этом, класс UserSessionModel имеет обязательное наследование AModel, для выполнения условия ограничения параметра T в универсального метода:

```
public class UserSessionModel : AModel
{
.....
}
```

Comment: Похоже это единственное решение... удалил неактуальные больше комментарии

Comment: @rdorn, пока я большего не смог придумать. В глубине души надеюсь можно решить это без рефлексии.

Comment: В текущей постановке вопроса либо рефлексия, либо swtch, увы. Возможно есть другое решение на уровне архитектуры

Comment: @rdorn, поэтому и написал, вдруг кто-то придумает. На уровне архитектуры тоже рассматривается, главное, чтобы решение было изящное и не усложняло код, не приводило к избыточности кода.
Рефлексия у меня ассоциируется с термином "абстракция", мне нравится думать в этом направлении, но увлекшись, можно наговнокодить. Во всяком случае Microsoft придумал перегрузку методов, перегрузку параметров методов... но мою идею как реализовать не нашел. По сути наверно подобие MVC из ASP.NET пытаюсь сделать только не в полной мере и для WindowsForms. (Forms в качестве View).

Comment: Посмотрите паттерны MVP и MVPVM, все уже придумано, и не требует экзотических решений.